# Row-based or column-based convention for storing data in multi-arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Suppose we have `m` vectors in `R^n` (or `R^(n,1)`) with `m >> n`.

We want to transform these by a linear transformation (applying a Matrix `A^(k, n)`) and by a translation given by a vector `b` in `R^n`. This is obviously faster with a 2D NumPy array then with a list of vectors.

When designing an API, would it be preferable to have a Matrix `V` of shape `(n, m)` or `(m, n)`?

The former, `V_1.shape = (n, m)`, is what we are used to from mathematics. It is easy to apply `A`, simply write `A @ V_1`. Translating `V_1` by `b` is not that easy though, we would need to reshape vector b in this case.

If `V_2.shape = (m, n)` then translating `V_2` by `b` is easy (thanks to NumPy broadcasting), but applying `A` to `V_2` couldn't be done by calculating `A @ V_2` anymore. Instead we would need to use something like `V_2 @ A.T`.

It appears (from limited research) that SciPy, Scikit usually prefer the latter convention (NumPy itself doesn't seem too opinionated on this problem). Why is that?

Note my question centers around which convention to use in terms of the API and not in regard to the [data layout in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74808537/why-does-numpy-use-row-based-data-as-opposed-to-column-based-data?noredirect=1#comment132025662_74808537).

Comment: What' s the role of the `k` dimension of `A`?  A `(m,n)@(n,k)=>(m,k)`, with `n` as the shared sum-of-products dimension.  That can't be translated by a (n,).  Have you looked at `np.einsum`?  Even if you don't use it in the final calculation, it's a good tool for thinking about combining dimensions.  It uses `einstein` notation to handle multidimensional arrays, which is widely used in physics.  While linear algebra tends to focus on 2d arrays (matrices and vectors), physics often has to work with higher dimensions.

Comment: The `k` is just supposed to indicate that the second dimension of `A` is arbitrary. I think there is a slight misunderstanding. I don't mean to translate the product with shape `(m, k)`, but rather the matrix that has shape `(m, n)`. That can be translated by a vector of shape `(n,)`. I haven't looked at `np.einsum` but on first glance it seems very interesting. I am however somewhat familiar with `einstein` summation notation.

Comment: You wrote `A @ V` and `V @ A.T`, but if only `V` is transposed, then I expect the two versions to be `A @ V` and `A @ V.T` since the matrix multiplication is not commutative (unless in some rare cases like [if the two matrices are diagonalisable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170241/when-is-matrix-multiplication-commutative)). "*SciPy, Scikit usually prefer the latter convention*" This is likely dependent of the actual operations. Which one do you use besides the matrix multiplication?

Comment: If `V` is (m,n), `A` is (n,k) and `b` is (k,), then `V@A+b` should produce a (m,k).

Comment: @hpaulj I want to look at matrix multiplication and translation separately. So I either want to calculate `A @ V` **or** `V + b`. I updated the question, I hope its more clear now.

Comment: @JérômeRichard `V` is also transposed, because we are changing the shape of `V` (its just implicit). I updated the question to make that more clear. Essentially, `V_1` and `V_2` are the transposed of each other, so you are right that in the case from `A @ V_1` => `V_1.T @ A.T = V_2 @ A.T`.